# Display dropdownlist selection with a label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a heck of a time all I want is this.

label.text = dropdownlist.text

How do I do that with a dropdownlist that is populated with a datasource in the visual studio designer?

I have an update statement that gets a parameter value from dropdownlist.text, why can't I just set the text property of the label the same way? I think I am missing something really simple but I can't find it.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditFruit" style="Z-INDEX: 159;
        LEFT:780px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 280px;"
        runat="server" DataSourceID="update" 
        DataTextField="fruit_id" DataValueField="fruit_id" 
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Selected ="True" Text="" Value ="">(Select)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>




private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (bxStarch.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        this.lblError.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.lblError.Visible = false;
        //string id = ddlEditFruit.SelectedValue.ToString();
        this.lblId.Visible = true;

        this.lblId.Text = ddlEditFruit.SelectedItem.Text;
        edit_fruit();
        reset_dropdowns();
        resest_dropdowns_2();
        fill_grd_fruit_id();
        fill_grd_size();
        fill_grd_progress();
        SetFocus(ddlGrade);
        change_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed this. It was in the wrong click event. I don't know how to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your codebehind, try this:

```
label.Text = dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text
```

`SelectedItem` will put the label text to some text, for instance "John"

`SelectedValue` will put the label text to some value, for instance "5".

Comment: Yeah!! It's not working that way. I am thinking it has something to do with the postback?? It is driving me nuts!! This should be the easiest thing to do ever!!

Comment: can you post some code? it'll be easier to figure out what the problem is that way

Comment: might be better to update your question, instead of posting as a comment :)

Comment: I entered the code but the format is all jacked up. Great way to start a monday!!

Comment: @briskovich check my update. Also, if you are filling those dropdownlists in your Page_Load method, try putting those methods inside a "if (!Page.isPostback).

Comment: I'm sorry guys!!! I had that in the wrong button click event!! It is definitely MONDAY!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `SelectedValue` of the `DropDownList`:

```
label.Text = dropdownlist.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label.Text = dropdownlist.SelectedValue
```

Will do that for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. I was trying to change the label value in the wrong click event. Silly error.